# JFrame not loading when Jar is launched through Windows Service

Tags: java, apache, jframe, windows-services, procrun

I installed my program in a Jar file as a Windows Service using Apache Procrun.

When I run it using the command start "`prunsrv.exe //TS//TestService`" it runs perfectly. But when I start the service in Windows services program, it doesn't launch the `JFrame`.

Yet the application does start as I can see the log entries. But related to the `JFrame` section, there are no exceptions yet it doesn't launch. Why does it not launch?

Answer (score 0):

Your service is not permitted to use the desktop, if it does not run as the current user (the owner of the desktop).
If so, the first call to `Dialog.open()` or other methods which paint on the desktop just hangs.

Comment: Is there any way to launch GUI through system account?

Comment: Was there any solution to this issue?